# Stripe: attach invoice pdf to email

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I'm currently trying to send emails with attached pdf invoices to customers with nodejs but I can't figure out how to get pdf file from invoice_pdf field.

I tried `fs`, `got` and `request` but I am not able to get the file content ever.

for example I tried:

```
let file = await got(invoice.invoice_pdf)
let fileContent = Buffer.from(file['body'])
...
// mail conf
attachments: [{
    'type': 'application/pdf',
    'name': invoice.number + '.pdf',
    'content': fileContent.toString('base64'),
}],
```

There is a pdf attached to the received email but it is a blank page with no content.

Any help?
Thanks a lot

EDIT: doc of Mandrill's attachments
[image]

Comment: The answer to this depends a bit on what form your mail service expects the pdf attachment in. Could you share the documentation for the tool you're using? The general approach though is to make a GET request using a library like axios to get the PDF data, then pass that to your email service as an attachment.

Comment: Hi ttmarek,
I just edited my post with Mandrill's documentation about attachments. I tested my code with the provided example and it worked fine.
I really think the problem comes from my `fileContent` since `invoice_pdf` does not directly point towards the actual file but to a page where the file is dynamically generated and downloaded in the browser

Comment: My suspicion that the issue has to do with how you're retrieving the PDF using `got`. I'm not too familiar with that library. It may be worthwhile opening up an issue on the project repo asking what the canonical way to fetch a PDF  in base64 would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We figured it out, using streams:

```
async function readFile(url: string): Promise<Buffer> {
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        const bufs = []
        let finalBuf = Buffer.from('')
        got.stream(url)
        .on('data', d => bufs.push(d))
        .on('end', async function () {
            finalBuf = Buffer.concat(bufs)
            resolve(finalBuf)
        })
        .on('error', reject)
    })
}

export async function sendInvoiceEmail(invoice: Stripe.Invoice) {
    try {
            ...
            const finalBuf = await readFile(invoice.invoice_pdf)

            const options = {
                ...
                attachments: [
                    {
                        'type': 'application/pdf',
                        'name': 'invoice.pdf',
                        'content': finalBuf.toString('base64'),
                    }
                ],
            }

            await MailerClient.send(options)
    } catch (err) {
        logger.error(err, 'Error while trying to send mail')
        throw err
    }
}
```

Thanks to those who tried to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the `NPM Package` `pdfreader` or `pdf2json` these packages will help you read the content firstly then you can store the data into a variable then pass it into the attachments.

Comment: I did but it wouldn't work because the `invoice_pdf` is like `https://pay.stripe.com/invoice/blibli/blabla/pdf`. It is not the actual file, the file is dynamically generated when accessing the url.
`pdfreader` and `pdf2json` both give error like `no such file`